# Why fixedSize error occurs depends on default parameter?

Tags: c++, opencv

I was trying to find a way how to make default parameter of *Mat type*, but it was complicated to make. But, today I found out this code **OutputArray _hist = Mat()** and I thought this could be simply a default parameter of *Mat type*. Therefore, I could make this code and it worked well, but I couldn't still understand one thing.

```
int myGetHistogram(InputArray _src, OutputArray _hist = Mat())
{
    Mat src = _src.getMat();
    _hist.create(512,512,CV_8U);
    Mat histImage = _hist.getMat();

    ...

    rectangle(histImage, max_pt1, max_pt2, Scalar(0), -1);
    return max_pt1.x/(histImage.cols/256);
}
```

In this code, this error message shows up.

*OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (!fixedSize() || ((Mat*)obj)->size.operator()() == _sz)*

If I set the default parameter as **OutputArray _hist = Mat(512,512,CV_8U)** instead of **OutputArray _hist = Mat()**, then the error is removed.
Why does this problem happen?

Comment: You should write a [mcve] and step through the call to `myGetHistogram` in the debugger. You will notice that [this `OutputArray` constructor](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/3.3.0/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp#L259) gets called. | You don't trigger the same problem in the second case, since `create` doesn't do anything (the size and type are already correct). Try a different size and it will happen again.

Comment: Notice that nowhere in the OpenCV code can we find this type of default value for `OutputArray`. At most it's a `cv::noArray`. I guess you should use that, and then call `_hist.needed()` to determine how to initialize `histImage`.

Comment: @DanMašek I tried a different size **OuptutArray _hist = Mat(512,256,CV_8U)** and error didn't occur. The reason why I tried to make a Mat type default parameter is that sometimes **OutputArray** isn't used. Sometimes only return value from **InputArray** should be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In either case you're creating an `OutputArray` from a temporary `Mat` (i.e. [this constructor](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/3.3.0/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp#L259)), so you won't be able to change the size or datatype.

Take inspiration from the OpenCV code. Use [`cv::noArray()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/dc/d84/group__core__basic.html#gad9287b23bba2fed753b36ef561ae7346) to make the output parameter optional, and then [`cv::OutputArray::needed`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/d2/d9e/classcv_1_1__OutputArray.html#a2ef2667f36017be9379d95fc5f421976) to determine how to initialize your `cv::Mat histImage`.

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int myGetHistogram(cv::InputArray _src, cv::OutputArray _hist = cv::noArray())
{
    cv::Mat src = _src.getMat();

    cv::Size const HISTOGRAM_SIZE(512, 512);

    cv::Mat histImage;
    if (_hist.needed()) {
        _hist.create(HISTOGRAM_SIZE, CV_8U);
        histImage = _hist.getMat();
    } else {
        histImage = cv::Mat(HISTOGRAM_SIZE, CV_8UC1);
    }

    // ... whatever

    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    cv::Mat a(4, 4, CV_8UC1);
    cv::Mat b;

    myGetHistogram(a);
    myGetHistogram(a, b);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm so glad that you provide me with some example code. By the way, I have one more question. As I read **Mat class** in openCV reference : https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#af1d014cecd1510cdf580bf2ed7e5aafc, and I thought it's also possible to allocate with **Mat()** and then reallocate with **create()**. But probably it seems wrong. Why is this not possible and **create()** after **Mat(size,depth)** is possible to work?